# Excel Search - Multiple results

Tags: excel

I am trying to build a search function within an excel file that will show multiple results based off of searching the name. I am not skilled in Excel and I found a template that I used to help me start. Unfortunately, I cannot get it working for multiple results.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj5Dq.png]

B-E is where my data is going to be stored. I have my search function at G3, which you can open by just typing the name and pressing enter. The results are being populated at I-L.

My function at I4 is

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$10,SMALL(IF(($G$3=$B$3:$B$10),ROW($B$3:$B$10)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$10))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1)))
```

I cannot however add this function to I5 without getting an error. I assume this is because of "ROWS" statement at the end of the function. I tried playing with the array and cannot figure out how to continue.

I understand this is basic stuff, but I have searched and cannot find a solution to my problem.

I also have tried to extend the function beyond B3:B10 to B:B so that we can continuously add data to sheet without having to edit the function. Is there a way to edit the formula to allow endless data to the B-E columns?

Comment: If your data set is large, think about using vba to automate the advanced filter.

Comment: Try use array formula and vlookup

Comment: VLOOKUP will not work as it will never return but the first match in Excel. @user11982798

Answer (score 0):

You must enter your formula as array formula.

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I put this in cell H2

```
=IF(A2:A11=F2,A2:D11,"")
```

I select range H2:K11, then press Ctrl + Shift + Enter, the formula become:

```
{=IF(A2:A11=F2,A2:D11,"")}
```

The Result will like this:

[image]